# Why am I getting a big spike in audio at the start of each sample in LabView?

Tags: labview, amplitude, dataflow-diagram

[image]

Everything else seems to be fine but at the start of each recording (1 second each) there's a big amplitude spike, I'm wondering what is causing it and how to fix it.

-I'm using the correct mic (it is recording audio properly)

-2 Channel

-16 bit resolution

-Duration of 1 second

-Sample Rate 48000Hz

Thanks in advance for any aid that you are able to provide!

Comment: I think it is noise when you turn on microphone. How about giving some delay between turning on microphone and starting to record sound data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an Express VI which will Initialise the hardware on start-up.

Rather open the diagram of the Express VI and recode it to have the Initialisation routine outside the While loop, and only the recording VI inside the loop.

Express VIs are not optimised for good coding practices.  :-)

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, I should look at what the VI does and basically copy it but change what I need?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. (Edited the answer to correct 'For' to 'While' loop, by the way.)

Comment: Sorry, thanks! Yes edit the code and optimise the operations.